# Merging over 2000 Cells using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have wrote the following code to merge cells in excel, the data is around 26000 rows, the code is running on core I7 CPU with 8 GB RAM, the problem that it still working since 4 days, the average rows per day is 3000 row!, any one know how to get the result, because its a report that should be delivered since three days!

```
Sub MergeCellss()
lastRow = Worksheets("A").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = 2 To lastRow
If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then
     intUpper = i
     Debug.Print ("<> -1 and <> +1 " & intUpper)
End If

If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then
     intUpper = i
     Debug.Print ("<> -1 and = +1 " & intUpper & " UPPPER LIMIT")
End If


If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 2).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Debug.Print ("<> +1 and = -1:" & i & "LOWER LIMIT")
        DoEvents
         For x = 1 To 8
             Range(Cells(intUpper, x), Cells(i, x)).Merge
        Next x

        For j = 18 To 26
             Range(Cells(intUpper, j), Cells(i, j)).Merge
        Next j
        Cells(intUpper, 14).Value = "=sumif(M" & CStr(intUpper) & ":M" & CStr(i) & ","">0"")"
        Range(Cells(intUpper, 14), Cells(i, 14)).Merge
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
End If

If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 2).Value And Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
     Debug.Print ("One Cells: " & i)
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 26)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
      Cells(intUpper, 14).Value = Cells(intUpper, 13).Value
      DoEvents
End If

Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

the code above will merge the all cells containing repeated data like User Name, Date of Birth, .... into one cell, and leave the training courses and experiences as it is.

I wonder how can I run this code in less than 1 hour.

Comment: You could start by posting some sample data together with expected result.

Comment: You are performing at least twice as many `If` checks as you need to. The first two `If ... End If : If ... End If` should be a single `If ... ElseIf ...End If`. The condition that is True most often should be the first one checked. If the first is True the second cannot be true so using `ElseIf` skips that calculation. The same goes for the second pair. Unfortunately you cannot`ElseIf` them all as the cells being checked changes from the first two to the second two but even pairing them up should drastically reduce calculation. A large variant array would reduce calc to <5% of what it is now.

Comment: My apologies - it looks like the latter two `If` statements can be nested into the first two with `ElseIf` . I hadn't realized that you'd flipped the cell references around and thought they were different cells but they are not. If any of those four conditions is true, none of the other three can be so there is no need to check them.

Comment: Why the DoEvents? You have events and screenupdating disabled. As best I can see all that line does is to thousands of times beg the operating system to take CPU cycles away from your program. Also -- why are you repeatedly setting DisplayAlerts to false? Isn't once enough?

Comment: Are you planning on posting a public link to redacted data at some point? It's kind of senseless to continue without some idea of the nature of the data. The best I can surmise is that column B contains dates and a switch in the relationship between three rows triggers different events.

Comment: As an experiment I filled a spreadsheet with random data, and looped through 50,000 rows , creating a merged cell in each row. Those 50,000 merges took about 15 seconds, so it would be surprising if the actual merging is what is causing the problem here. Some important clue hasn't been given.

Comment: @JohnColeman - I concur. An older i5/8Gb laptop ran through 24K lines of data in 57 seconds but I have no way of knowing how many of each operation the actual data would produce. I fear background processes are commandeering the `DoEvents`. I'll post some modified code in case the OP wants to try it.

Comment: @Jeeped first of all thank you very much for being the first one to answer my question, its great to have immediate help when needed, I took your advice, removed the if's and also removed the doEvents, ran the code for 30 minutes without success, it still running as old days, I don't know any thing about the progress  because I removed all debug's

Comment: @Jeeped yes, I agree with you, but after many trials, I pasted values of all data, and even removed all formats, tried the code while the file is Excel 1997-2003 format, and 2007 format, and excel binary, but all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rewrite on your code. The two primary differences are the use of `If ... ElseIf ... End If` and the grouping of the first and fourth conditional operations (the conditions were the same).

```
Sub Merge_Cells()
    Dim lastRow As Long, rw As Long
    Dim intUpper As Long, x As Long
    Dim vVALs As Variant

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
    Debug.Print Timer

    With Worksheets("A")
        .Cells(1, 1) = Timer
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For rw = 2 To lastRow
            vVALs = Array(.Cells(rw - 1, 2).Value, .Cells(rw, 2).Value, .Cells(rw + 1, 2).Value)

            If vVALs(1) <> vVALs(0) And vVALs(1) <> vVALs(2) Then
                'the first and fourth conditions were the same so they are both here
                'original first If condition
                intUpper = rw
                'Debug.Print ("<> -1 and <> +1 " & intUpper)
                'original fourth If condition
                'Debug.Print ("One Cells: " & rw)
                .Range(.Cells(rw, 1), .Cells(rw, 26)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
                .Cells(intUpper, 14).Value = .Cells(intUpper, 13).Value
            ElseIf vVALs(1) <> vVALs(0) And vVALs(1) = vVALs(2) Then
                 intUpper = rw
                 'Debug.Print ("<> -1 and = +1 " & intUpper & " UPPPER LIMIT")
            ElseIf vVALs(1) = vVALs(0) And vVALs(1) <> vVALs(2) Then
                'Debug.Print ("<> +1 and = -1:" & rw & "LOWER LIMIT")

                For x = 1 To 26
                    If x < 9 Or x > 17 Then _
                        .Range(.Cells(intUpper, x), .Cells(rw, x)).Merge
                Next x

                .Cells(intUpper, 14).Value = "=sumif(M" & CStr(intUpper) & ":M" & CStr(rw) & ","">0"")"
                .Range(.Cells(intUpper, 14), .Cells(rw, 14)).Merge
                .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 26).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
            End If

        Next rw
        .Cells(1, 2) = Timer
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer
    appTGGL
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
End Sub
```

I've also read the three primary conditional values into a variant array to reduce repeated worksheet value reads.

Comment: Thank for the code, I ran it before 20 minutes, and still waiting for it to finish the first timer showed (debug.print Timer) is 25895.95, here is a snapshot of the data <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=2vkn886" target="_blank">